# Is CosmosDB a purely key-value database?

Tags: azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

Is Cosmo DB a purely key-value database like DynamoDB? What does it mean when the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/faq) says that Cosmos DB support various data models such as key/value, columnar, document, and graph?

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB stores data in the JSON format and it has a [`table API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-introduction), which is key-value storage.

Cosmos DB offers a multitude of APIs to access and query data including, SQL, various popular OSS APIs, and native support for NoSQL workloads.​

Use key-value, tabular, graph, and document data​

Comment: So it is a key value database. What does the statement `Cosmos DB support various data models such as key/value, columnar, document, and graph` mean then?

Comment: it means the type of APIs

Comment: I did not understand. Could you please explain with a small example?

Comment: Here you go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/data-store-overview

Comment: What does it mean for cosmodb to be called multi model? Does it not always acts as a key-value store?

Comment: multi model means it supports any form of data document,keyvalue,graph,columnar. it acts based on the way you create the account where sql api, grelmin, mongo etc

Comment: Okay. I created with sql api, does that make it a keyvalue store?

Comment: It looks like Azure Cosmos DB will use a document database when you select the SQL API. Quote: "Select Core (SQL) to create a document database and query by using SQL syntax. The API determines the type of account to create. Azure Cosmos DB provides five APIs: Core (SQL) and MongoDB for document data, Gremlin for graph data, Azure Table, and Cassandra. Currently, you must create a separate account for each API."

Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-cosmosdb-resources-portal